# Read csv file auto delimeter

Tags: python-3.x, csv, python-3.6

I have a small script that reads a pipe '|' delimited csv file and then writes it to another file as comma delimited.  It works fine.  Code, input file and output file below:

```
import csv


ifile = "d:\\python\\project\\cars-original.csv"
ofile = "d:\\python\\project\\cars.csv"

with open(ifile, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    with open(ofile, 'w', newline='') as of:
        writer = csv.writer(of, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

`Reading|Make|Model|Type|Value
Reading 0|Toyota|Previa|distance|19.83942
Reading 1|Dodge|Intrepid|distance|31.28257`


`Reading,Make,Model,Type,Value
Reading 0,Toyota,Previa,distance,19.83942
Reading 1,Dodge,Intrepid,distance,31.28257`

I now want to modify the script so that it can auto-read the delimiter type.

I have found several examples online, but when I run mine I get a blank file for output.  No errors, just blank.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

My modified (broken) script:

```
import csv


ifile = "d:\\python\\projects\\cars-original.csv"
ofile = "d:\\python\\projects\\cars.csv"


with open(ifile, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.read(1024), delimiters=',|')
    with open(ofile, 'w', newline='') as of:
        writer = csv.writer(of, dialect)
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
import csv


ifile = "d:\\python\\project\\cars-original.csv"
ofile = "d:\\python\\project\\cars.csv"


with open(ifile, 'r') as f:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.readline(), [',', '|'])
    f.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect)
    with open(ofile, 'w', newline='') as of:
        writer = csv.writer(of, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example in Python documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) file pointer is moved to the beginning of the file, right after the dialect detection.

```
with open('example.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))
    csvfile.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
```

Comment: Your suggestion allows the file to be written, but the delimiter is no longer updated.  Input file and output file are both pipe delimited.